# Index where condition is true. Efficiency and brevity

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

```
this_is_my_dataframe_with_a_long_name
```

I would like to find the indices where a condition is `True`. For example, let's say that the condition is that `column` is equal to `value`.

I know I can technically do:

```
dataframe_with_a_long_name[dataframe_with_a_long_name['column'] =='A].index
```

This makes me wonder:

1. Is the above the **most efficient** way to do retrieve those indices? Note that the code above creates a temporary copy of True/False values, uses this output to index the dataframe, and then retrieves the index of the resulting view.
2. Is there a more **concise way** of running this query? For example,  `idxmin()` allows one to directly query the index for the smallest value (one method call). Is there anything equivalent for retrieving indices where a condition is `True`? e.g.:

   ```
   data_frame_with_a_long_name['column' == 'A'].true_indices()
   ```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com    .... also `df = dataframe_with_a_long_name #now use df instead ...`

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley Using `df` requires creating an additional variable alias just for a single statement. Keeping track of such short aliases (to avoiding clashes) is not trivial. Also, please see my note about **efficiency**, which is what I care most about in this question.

Comment: then use the long name ... theres nothing wrong with that ... in terms of efficiency ... is this too slow? have you profiled it to make sure this is the bottle neck? often these operations aver very fast since they are vectorized over into c land ... (although its actually slower if your arrays are too small)

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley Is that relatively efficient then? (no copies, etc. are created or moved around?)

Comment: see my edit ... python is typically a language where you assume its fast enough until you encounter a situation where it isnt... then you peephole optimize whatever the bottleneck is to make it as fast as you can

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley I am working with a dataframe with ~70M rows. I hope my question still makes sense. Either way, I am interested in how to write efficient Pandas code, regardless of the specifics of my current dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

In regular pandas, that's likely best way to write it.  As the Dataframe gets larger, there may be some speedup using the newer [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#performance-of-query) method, which will generally be more concise, especially given a longer Dataframe name.

```
In [154]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000000), columns=['a'])

In [155]: %timeit df[df['a'] < .25].index
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop

In [156]: %timeit df.query('a < .25').index
1 loops, best of 3: 129 ms per loop
```

Edit:

As @Jeff, notes, if you only need indices, the fastest path is actually this:

```
In [160]: %timeit df.index[df['a'] < .25]
10 loops, best of 3: 81.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: if you ONLY need the indices, then ``df.index[df['a']<0.25]`` will be the fastest.